# ld: framework not found FirebaseFirestore

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

When building my application using the **.xcworkspace** with a Generic iOS Device, I get the error message:

```
ld: framework not found FirebaseFirestore
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

The application is compiling without this error when I build & run on my iPhone and on the iOS Simulator.

Does anyone have advice on debugging this? I've tried pod de-integration, installation, using specific targets specified from Github, removing targets, etc.

Thank you!